# Does this mean some Wall-Sun-Sun primes have already been found?

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

In the [PrimeGrid project statistics page](http://prpnet.primegrid.com:13001/server_stats.html) for Wall-Sun-Sun Prime Search, it says,

```
Wall-Sun-Suns ... 2
Near Wall-Sun-Suns ... 208
```

However, all the internet search results for Wall-Sun-Sun primes seem to state that no such numbers have been found so far. But then again, the search range has nearly doubled since the [last public update](http://www.primegrid.com/forum_thread.php?id=3008&nowrap=true#45946) of March 2014, cited in Wikipedia and other resources. Has the search just gotten successful or am I misinterpreting the table from [[1](http://prpnet.primegrid.com:13001/server_stats.html)]?

Comment: If you look at the [user finds](http://prpnet.primegrid.com:13001/user_finds.html), user zunewantan has (reported to have?) found some apparently in April or perhaps even May. I'd think they'd be carefully double-checked before being officially announced, so it may be a matter of days until they are confirmed or refuted.

Comment: Interesting about those primes is that infinite many are expected although still none is known (see below answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very interesting in Wall-Sun-Sun numbers, so I investigate [Primegrid forum](http://www.primegrid.com/forum_thread.php?id=4196&nowrap=true#75972). Two Wall-Sun-Sun were "discovered" on April 28th and May 3rd, but both are false, because of some "computation error" and "due to an overclock". Anyway, there is no known Wall-Sun-Sun prime.